# How to pass parameters to an ADF pipeline from Schedule type trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to pass parameters to an ADF pipeline from Schedule type trigger?

Comment: Put the trigger in a Logic App instead of ADF. Have the Logic App call the Data Factory and pass the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Joel Cochran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

First, add parameter to your pipeline:

[image]

And then you can edit the json file of your trigger:

```
{
    "name": "trigger2",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline3",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "test1": "111"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2020-08-06T02:18:00.000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger-definition

On my side it is no problem, please have a try on your side.

Comment: It worked. If we create a parameter to pipeline and click on add trigger,  select schedule and upon save trigger,  the created parameter will magically appear on the add trigger UI!

Comment: If it is a hard-coded value, then why use a parameter at all? A variable would work just fine. My general assumption is that parameters are dynamic dependency values from outside the pipeline.

Comment: @Joel Cochran i have created an azure sql  metadata driven framework using ADF lookup activity. Now that i have configured multiple jobs for same pipeline,  i want to pass the job name from the Trigger so that corresponding metadata is picked up and executed.

Comment: That makes sense - I have also created a similar framework, but I use Logic Apps as the meta-orchestrator, so passing variables in is straightforward.